# ByVal with a range in which formulas are used.

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Hvis du på noget tidspunkt tilføjer flere rows, så sig til.
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("B27:B33"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=UDF_Now()"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am using the following VBA code to execute my user defined function whenever a cell value in the Range("B27:B33") changes.

This works fine, as long as I am changing the cell values in the range manually. The issue is now that I want this macro to work for a given range that is made up by formulas. Whenever I change any of the precedents, a cell value of the range changes, but my macro does not execute.

I want this to work with formulas, so that the macro gets executed whenever I change a precedent and thus change the values of the cells within the range.

I hope this is useful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The Change Event code doesn't get triggered when the cell content is changed due to a formula.
If you want to trigger a event when the value is being changed by a formula, you may consider **Worksheet_Calculate** also along with change event code if that is also required.